# Extract date from file name in python, not fixed name

Tags: python, regex, timestamp, filenames

I need to get date from file name in python code. I found many solutions, but from fixed name and date. But I dont know what the name of the file will be, date is changing. How to do that?

I have a code which is working for known file name (current date), file is called micro20230125.txt

```
import re

import os
from datetime import datetime

header = """#SANR0000013003;*;#CNR0010;*;#RINVAL-777.0;*;"""

current_timestamp = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
input_file = "micro" + current_timestamp + ".txt"
output_file = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0] + ".zrxp"


with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    first_line = f.readline().strip('\n')

    text = re.search('(\d{6})', first_line).group(1)



text = header + "\n" + text + "\n"

with open(output_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
    print(text)
`
```

but I dont need current date. I will get file with some random date, so how can I extract unknown date from file name? How to change this variable current_timestamp?

I tried to use regex but I messed something up

**EDIT: DIFF CODE, SIMILAR PROBLEM:**

I was dealing with this code and then realized: python doesnt know what those numbers in name represent, so why treat them like a date and complicate things? Those are just numbers. As a matter of fact, I need those numbers as long as full file name. So I came up with different code.

```
import re
import os

def get_numbers_from_filename(filename):
    return re.search(r'\d+', filename).group(0) #returns only numbers

for filename in os.listdir("my path"):
   print (get_numbers_from_filename(filename))

def get_numbers_from_filename(filename):
   return re.search(r"(.)+", filename).group(0) #returns all name



for filename in os.listdir("my path"):
       print(get_numbers_from_filename(filename))
```

file was: micro20230104.txt

and result is:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucti9.png)

Now, I want to use that result, dont want to print it.
No matter how I get that returns me error.

```
import re
import os


def get_numbers_from_filename(filename):
    return re.search(r"(.)+", filename).group(0)


for filename in os.listdir("my path"):
    print(get_numbers_from_filename(filename))
    m = get_numbers_from_filename(filename)
    output_file = os.path.splitext(m)[0] + ".zrxp"

       with open(m, "r") as f:
           first_line = f.readline().strip('\n')

           text = re.search('(\d{6})', first_line).group(1)

       text = header + "\n" + text + "\n"

       with open(output_file, "w") as f:
           f.write(text)
           print(text)
```

but it it says error
[error:there is no such file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IgrV.png)

what to do? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a consistent order for the file names?? for example: all files start with 'micro' and then with date.txt (micro[date].txt) or the name at the beginning could change?

Comment: yes, name of the file will be micro.... (some date after it but I dont know in advance which one is it)

Comment: `'(\d{6})'` - this will fail if you have some 6-digit number in the file name that is not a date. However, if you know that your date will be in %Y%m%d format, you have more information than "it has 6 digits" - along the lines of "first digit will always be a 2, followed by 0" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case all the files have the format 'micro[YearMonthDay].txt', you can try this solution:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

header = """#SANR0000013003;*;#CNR0010;*;#RINVAL-777.0;*;"""

#Change the variable folder_path for your actual directory path.
folder_path = "\\path_files\\"
filenames = []
# Iterate directory
for path in os.listdir(folder_path):
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, path)):
        filenames.append(path)

dates = []
for filename in filenames:
    # First solution:
    filename = filename.replace('micro', '')
    filename = filename.replace('.txt', '')
    date = datetime.strptime(filename, "%Y%m%d")

    # Second solution:
    # date = datetime.strptime(filename, "micro%Y%m%d.txt")

    dates.append(date)

for date in dates:
    print(date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))

    with open(f'.\\micro{date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}.txt', "r") as f:
        first_line = f.readline().strip('\n')

    text = re.search('(\d{6})', first_line).group(1)

    text = header + "\n" + text + "\n"

    with open(output_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(text)
        print(text)
```

Use the solution you prefer and comment the other one.

**Testing:**

1. Text files for test

[image: Text files for test]

2. Code

[image: Code]

3. Result

[image: Result]

I hope I could help! :D

Comment: it gives me error with date. I'm trying to manipulate it for hour already, nothing gives me results :(

C:\python-udemy\python-projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\python-udemy\python-projects\regex_7.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python-udemy\python-projects\regex_7.py", line 19, in <module>
    date = datetime.strptime(filename, "%Y%m%d")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: That's the hole error?? It should display some info. @Aida

Comment: @Aida I have edited the answer and leave you some pictures of files, code and results.

Comment: JLMelandri8 that is perfect, thank you! Will be using it in future for sure. Thanks alot! I have been working on it a diff way and came across some other issue.